# Multiple intent depends on radio button selected

Tags: java, android, if-statement

It is possible to go to specific class base on what radio button selected?
And it is possible to make an if-else statement in onClick for the new intent?

For example,

Circle, Square, Triangle radio group button.
Circle has been selected.

In "onClick"
There is a if-else statement that has "circle.class", "square.class", "triangle.class"
The intent will go to "circle.class"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible!
All ya gotta do is call the mainn method of the required class(or any other method)
If the method is static,call it directly through class reference, it it is non-static then use an object of that class(take care of the NullPointerException though)

1)Make sure your circle or triangle(or whatever) classes are created

Either you can :
Under the ActionPerformed() event for jRadioButton1

```
   // should be the name of your button, say CircleActionPerformed() 
   private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {  
       
        if(jRadioButton.isSelected() == true)
        {
                circle.main() // 
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the Way, is OnClick a Button or what?

Comment: OnClick a button sir. I tried like this "if ("Circle".equals(radioButton.getText().toString())){}" but the error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference at com.example.locator.myapplication.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)"

Comment: Try using the isSelected()== true instead of getText().